# Determining the sample space of a random experiment problem

Tags: probability, dice

A die is rolled continually until a 6 appears, at which point the experiment stops. What is the sample space of this experiment?

Let $E_n$ denotes the event that $n$ rolls are necessary to complete the experiment. What points of the sample space are contained in $E_n$?

What points of the sample space are contained in $(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}E_n)^\mathsf{c}$?

Comment: The sample space consists of possible outcomes of the experiment. So what matters is the numbers  that come up when you roll the dice. All you require is that you are to stop when a six comes up. Can you write down some elements of the sample space now? For example, is $(1,2,3,6)$ in the sample space? Is $(4,4,5,7,6)$ in the sample space? Is $(2,6,4,6)$ in the sample space? Thinking in this fashion will be helpful for you : taking examples helps in generalization.

Comment: Yet the last part of the question remains unclear to me.

Comment: The last part must be tackled last. Please ensure that the first part is clear : what I mean is, can you clearly write down/describe the sample space of this experiment? Can  you describe $E_n$?If you cannot do this, then the last part will of course not be clear. If you can, then show the answer : I will confirm it, and then we can proceed to the last part.